# Only allow a click on an element after 500ms has passed

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make everything inside the .on() function run if only 500ms has passed since the element was last clicked on? I'm trying to make this work so that you can't rapid fire click on the element. I want clicks to only register if 500ms has passed since the last click.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.next, a.prev, nav ul a', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    //Set side nav item to be active
    var page = $(this).data("page");
    var sectionClicked = $(this).data("section");
    var currentSection = $("body").attr("data-current-section");
    var currentPage = $("body").attr("data-current-page");

    if($(this).hasClass("side_nav_link")){
        var section = $(this).data("section");

        ga('send', 'event', {
          'eventCategory': 'Side Nav',
          'eventAction': 'Click',
          'eventLabel': section
        });
    }

    if($(this).hasClass("next") ){
        ga('send', 'event', {
          'eventCategory': 'Prev/Next Links',
          'eventAction': 'Click',
          'eventLabel': 'Next'
        });
    }

    if($(this).hasClass("prev") ){
        ga('send', 'event', {
          'eventCategory': 'Prev/Next Links',
          'eventAction': 'Click',
          'eventLabel': 'Prev'
        });
    }


    loadContent(page, sectionClicked, currentSection, currentPage);

});
```

Comment: If you're using lodash, you could use [`throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle).

Comment: I'd be sure to disable and re-enable the button, so the user knows it is timed out, and not just failing to respond. Make sure you have a visual cue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the value of `this` to another variable and create a setTimeout.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.next, a.prev, nav ul a', function(e){

    // prevent defaults
    e.preventDefault();

    // add this to new variable
    var parentThis = this;

    // set the timeout function
    setTimeout(function(){

        //Set side nav item to be active
        var page           = $(parentThis).data("page"),
            sectionClicked = $(parentThis).data("section"),
            currentSection = $("body").attr("data-current-section"),
            currentPage    = $("body").attr("data-current-page");

        if($(parentThis).hasClass("side_nav_link")){
            var section = $(parentThis).data("section");
            ga('send', 'event', {
                'eventCategory': 'Side Nav',
                'eventAction': 'Click',
                'eventLabel': section
            });
        }

        if($(parentThis).hasClass("next") ){
            ga('send', 'event', {
                'eventCategory': 'Prev/Next Links',
                'eventAction': 'Click',
                'eventLabel': 'Next'
            });
        }

        if($(parentThis).hasClass("prev") ){
            ga('send', 'event', {
                'eventCategory': 'Prev/Next Links',
                'eventAction': 'Click',
                'eventLabel': 'Prev'
            });
        }

        loadContent(page, sectionClicked, currentSection, currentPage);

    }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via `setTimeout` and making a `toggled` variable.

```
var toggled = false
(document).on('click', '#target', function(e){
    if(!toggled){
        toggled = true
        setTimeout(function(){
            toggled = false
        },500)
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

If the click is not toggled (Eg, waiting around for 500ms), it will do the thing, and then set a timer for 500ms, and then allow it to do the thing again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickInProgress = false;
$(document).on('click', 'a.next, a.prev, nav ul a', function(e){
if(clickInProgress) return;
clickInProgress = true;
//..

setTimeout(function() { clickInProgress = false; }, 500);
});
```

That's a bit hacky, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a condition, if set boolean variable is true, the click event is possible. Once the user clicks on it, it changes into false with a timer, that after `amount` of time it will become `true` and the click event will be possible again.

```js
var bool = true;

$(document).on('click', '.box', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

   //your code

  if (bool) {
    console.log('clicked&passed');
    bool = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      bool = true;
    }, 500);
  }

});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='box'></div>
```